# Get/Set serial class properties

Tags: python, inheritance, pyserial

I'm using PySerial to connect to a Threaded connection. This is my simplified 1st class inheriting Thread and running serial:

```
from threading import Thread
import serial, inspect

class Serial1(Thread):

def __init__(self,main_queue,port = "COM1")

    self.ser = serial.Serial()
    self.queue = main_queue
    self.port = port

def open(self):

    self.ser.port = self.port
    if self.ser.isOpen():
        self.ser.close()
    self.ser.open()
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.start()
```

After that I made another similar class Serial2 that inherits Thread and uses Serial1:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import serial1

class Serial2(Thread):

def __init__(self,main_queue,port = "COM2")

    self.ser = serial1.Serial1()
    self.queue = main_queue
    self.port = port

def open(self):
    self.ser = serial1.Serial1(self.queue, self.port)
    if self.ser.open() == True:
        Thread.__init__(self)
        if self.isAlive() == False:
            self.start()
```

Having done all that, how do I set/get the serial's port property on both Serial1 and Serial2? Suppose I'm using Serial1 and Serial2 in a script:

```
from Queue import Queue
import serial2
import serial1

q1 = Queue(maxsize = 1)
q2 = Queue(maxsize = 1)

s1 = serial1.Serial1(q1, "COM4" )
s2 = serial2.Serial2(q2, "COM2" )

#get port value from Serial1 and Serial2
port1 = s1.port
port2 = s2.port

#set Serial1 and Serial2 port value
s1.port = "COM3"
s2.port = "COM1"
```

I've tried using getter/setters in Serial1 before, but they resulted in an infinite recursion:

```
def getport(self): 
    return self.port

def setport(self, port): #when first initialising self.port, it goes and get stuck here
    self.port = port

port = property(getport,setport)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing.

I've finally got an answer, which is rather short:

```
def getport(self): 
    return self.ser.port

def setport(self, port):
    self.ser.port = port

port = property(getport,setport)
```